# How to read and parse a big STL file?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

How to read and parse a big STL file? I write a application to view the 3D STL file. The 3D STL file can be binary or ACSII. I need to read the STL file from sdcard and then parse the data to render using OpenGL. But I have the "out of memory" when the 3D STL is big. How to fix this problem. I use two arraylists to store the facet formal and vertex.

The below code is implemented "read and parse the binary STL file":

```
private void processBinarySTL(){
    Thread processThread =new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            File file=new File("/mnt/sdcard/3D/Lost_Pleiade_Ready.stl");

            InputStream inputStream = null;
            try {
                inputStream = mContext.getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri.fromFile(file));
                int n = 0;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[4];
                inputStream.skip(80);
                n = inputStream.read(buffer);
                System.out.println("n=="+n);
                int size=getIntWithLittleEndian(buffer,0);
                System.out.println("size=="+size);
                List<Float> normalList=new ArrayList<Float>();
                List<Float> vertexList = new ArrayList<Float>();
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                    //normal
                    for(int k=0;k<3;k++){
                    inputStream.read(buffer);
                    normalList.add(Float.intBitsToFloat(getIntWithLittleEndian(buffer, 0)));
                    }


                    for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
                    inputStream.read(buffer);
                    float x = Float.intBitsToFloat(getIntWithLittleEndian(buffer, 0));
                    inputStream.read(buffer);
                    float y = Float.intBitsToFloat(getIntWithLittleEndian(buffer, 0));
                    inputStream.read(buffer);
                    float z = Float.intBitsToFloat(getIntWithLittleEndian(buffer, 0));
                    adjustMaxMin(x, y, z);
                    vertexList.add(x);
                    vertexList.add(y);
                    vertexList.add(z);
                    }
                    inputStream.skip(2);

                }
                System.out.println("normalList size== "+normalList.size());
                System.out.println("vertexList size== "+vertexList.size());
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                if(inputStream!=null)
                    try {
                        inputStream.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }

        }
    });
    processThread.start();
}
```

Comment: are you looking for http://code.j3d.org/javadoc/org/j3d/loaders/stl/STLFileReader.html

Comment: @KarthikT Thank you for your reply. I don't know this resource. I will study it.

Comment: @KarthikT I have a look about j3d. But It not my solution. I need implement "view 3D STL File" in Android application.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to solve out of memory issues in situations like this is to increase the maximum memory allocation of the JVM. This can be set using the `-Xmx` command line switch and specifying a larger maximum memory usage.

eg.
`java Main -Xmx 2G` would set the maximum memory usage of program Main to be 2 GB.  The default maximum memory allocation is 1/4 of your physical memory.

See: http://javarevisited.blogspot.sg/2011/11/hotspot-jvm-options-java-examples.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you still need a solution for your problem. As your Post really helped me by developing a small STL-Binary Reader I want to give you somwething back.
I also discovered these strange Out of Memorys with my own apps. The reason is that android just gives you a really small amount of memory by default (depends on your device). Before API version 11 you had to increase your memory manually. Now andby using API level 11 you can avoid these problems by "largeHeap".
Just put a declaration in your android manifest looking like this:

```
<application
        android:largeHeap="true"
                ....     >
                ....
</application>
```

More information you can find in other threads here in Stack Overflow by searching for "How to increase heap size of an android application?".

Answer (score 0):

The memory issue is caused by using an arraylist. by default java initializes an arraylist to have a size of 10, as you add the 11th element the array is copied to a new array and given double the room (so a size of 20), each time you pass the current size of the array it is copied and doubled in size. you can solve this by initializing the arraylist to have a size big enough to store all values without growing.

```
List<Float> normalList=new ArrayList<Float>(sizeOfArray);
List<Float> vertexList = new ArrayList<Float>(sizeOfOtherArray);
```